# Using android.app.Fragment with ViewPager in Android 3.0+

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-viewpager

I am developing app with android:minSdkVersion="11". From what I know, ViewPager is implemented within Compatibility Library. I have succeed to make it work in my application by adding android-support-v4.jar library, but now I am obliged to use

> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

because I need getSupportFragmentManager() for FragmentPagerAdapter, instead of new android.app.Activity's getFragmentManager().

Also I need to use

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment

instead of

> android.app.Fragment

It works though, I definitely don't like this approach. It destroys design of app, and I don't want to have Compatibility Library in my API Level 11 project at all.

Are there other more native ways to use ViewPager in Honeycomb+ apps?

Comment: Accepted answer should [change](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16067755/1747491) now that `v13` is released.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may not have been the case at the time the accepted answer was stated, but there's `import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;` in the [sample code](https://github.com/search?q=android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter%20repo%3aandroid/platform_development%20repo%3acommonsguy/cw-omnibus%20extension%3ajava&type=Code). If you use support-v13 library the constructor takes a non-support version of the `FragmentManager`. Note that the `ViewPager` must still come from v4.

I'll also add that v4 means support library for Android version 4+ (Donut 1.6), and v13 means support library for Android version 13+ (Honeycomb 3.2). Just a fact that wasn't immediately obvious to me at least. Meaning the APIs used in v4/v13 are compatible with and versions back to that point.

Answer (score 8):

Copy `FragmentPagerAdapter` into your code and modify it to use `android.app.Fragment`, etc. Or implement your own `PagerAdapter` yourself, it does not depend on fragments at all.

Comment: You mean I can also use ViewPager code in my app, after modifying it? Where can I get the source of Compatibility Library? Is it the only way for Honeycomb, nothing more native or universal?

Comment: The download includes the source. If you installed it from the SDK manager it would be in $SDK_ROOT/extras/android/compatibility/v4/src. Don't know what you mean by 'native or universal', but `ViewPager` is not part of the Android SDK, you have to add it to your project to use it, either in library (jar) or source form.

Comment: I have copied FragmentPagerAdapter and made it work with android.app.Fragment. But this approach still assume that I have to use android-support-v4.jar library. Is it normal approach at all?

Comment: Define normal :) As I said, ViewPager is not in the SDK, so you have to add it to your project. Either copy all related code to your project, or add `android-support-v4.jar` (as your doing now). There is really no other way to use it. Using the jar is slightly better, because you can simply replace it when they release an update.

Comment: By normal, I am trying to describe an approach that had already recommended itself well in different apps. For apps with minSDK < 11, it is just using of android-support-v4.jar. And seems like the only option for honeycomb+ apps is this mess we described here :) At least for now. Thanks a lot for your help. Кстати, привет 東京 из 上海-я.

Comment: Tried to take FragmentPagerAdapter, move it to my project and replace the Fragment, etc. imports to the android.app.* ones... This didn't work as FragmentPagerAdapter calls some methods that only exist in api level 14 (for instance: FragmentTransaction.attach, or Fragment.setMenuVisibility).   :(